# Android maps setZoom(19)

Tags: android, google-maps

I have one marker displayed and centered in my `ItemizedOverlay` in maps, currently I call `setZoom(19)`.

But how can I control the zoom level? i.e. I want to zoom in as detailed as possible, but still showing the map in satellite mode clear.

I have noticed that if you zoom in to far everything just goes black. How can I zoom into the most detailed level without going to far?

Any help most appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
setZoom(mapview.getMaxZoomLevel());
```

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView

Comment: Still having the same problem. I get a black screen and have to zoom out twice by pressing the minus sign (mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true)), before seeing the landscape on map

Comment: Noticed that when you search on an address in California US, you could not zoom out so far that it turned black. In the most detailed zoom level the map was always visible.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is: look at the UiSettings in api v2 reference, there is the "setMaxZoomLevel" and "setMinZoomLevel".
Setup the max zoom level to the one that doesn't show a black screen (make some tests), then call the setZoom(mapview.getMaxZoomLevel());

Regards.